# Induced e.m.f per unit length being equal

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction

Apparently the induced e.m.f per unit length in a closed circuit placed in a varying magnetic field is the same throughout the length of the loop.

Can anyone provide a proof for this, preferably not involving complicated calculus or physics above high-school level? Googling doesn't yield much.

Answer (score 1):

The induced e.m.f. is directly proportional to the number of turns. It per comes directly from Faraday's law of induction:

$$v=-N\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$

or

$$\frac{v}{N}=-\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$

Where

$v$= the induced voltage

$N$= the number of turns

$\phi$= the average magnetic flux (webers) enclosed by each turn

So from the above, for a given magnetic flux the induced voltage $v$ per turn is constant throughout the coil.

Hope this this helps

Comment: This works fine for solenoids, but can you provide a more general proof? Does it involve a lot of complicated physics?

Comment: Your post talked about the inductance associated with a loop. Are you interested in a different configuration? I'm unclear what it is you want a general proof of.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a general closed circuit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a complete circular loop of uniform wire completely within a uniform magnetic field that is changing with time, symmetry requires that the emf/unit length (in the loop) should be a constant.  (There is no prefered point of view.)  Current will flow in the loop and the emf in each segment will be dissipated by the IR drop. There will be no voltage difference between any to points in the loop.  If you cut the loop at some point, the current will stop, charges will build up on each side of the cut, and the total emf will be expressed as a voltage drop across the cut.  If you have a complete loop which is not a circle, you lose symmetry.  The magnetic emf/unit length can vary from point to point in the loop, but the current must be the same at each point.  This means there must be a redistribution of charge around the loop to give an electric field which compensates for the variations in the magnetic emfs. There will still be no voltage difference between any two points in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

> Apparently the induced e.m.f per unit length in a closed circuit placed in a varying magnetic field is the same throughout the length of the loop.

Let's forget about induced e.m.f. for a moment, and just consider the E-field in a wire. The "microscopic" Ohm's law says:

$$\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E}$$

where $\vec{J}$ is the current density at a point, $\vec{E}$ is the electric field at a point, and $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the conductor at that point.

By this law, if the current density is uniform throughout a wire, and the conductivity is uniform throughout the wire, then the electric field must be uniform throughout the wire.

It just so happens that in a conductor, electrons re-arrange themselves to ensure that the current is uniform (constant) along the length of a wire. And this, in turn, ensures that the E field is uniform (constant) along the length of the wire.

The electric field in a wire is a *vector* field. It has a direction. However, a wire may be curved, and the current will "curve" and the E field will "curve".  But we may say that the *magnitude* of the E field in a wire with a uniform (constant) linear conductivity will be uniform (constant).

This may be why you believe that

> Apparently the induced e.m.f per unit length in a closed circuit placed in a varying magnetic field is the same throughout the length of the loop

However, the e.m.f. induced per unit length in a wire, is not necessarily the same throughout the wire.

The electric field in a wire which is excited by a time-varying magnetic field consists of two components. There is the electric field that is induced by the time-varying magnetic field, and there is an electric field that is generated by the re-arrangement of electrons in the wire. These add up to the total electric field, and it is this total electric field that is uniform through the (uniform) wire.

That part of the electric field that is induced by the time-varying magnetic field, we designate by $\vec{E_{rot}}$, and the e.m.f. induced in a segment of wire is given by the formula

$$ \mathscr E_{induced} = \int_C \vec{E_{rot}} \cdot d\vec{\ell}$$

In general, it will NOT be the case that $\vec{E_{rot}}$ or $\mathscr E_{induced}$ is uniform throughout the length of a wire, unless the geometry of the circuit makes it so. For example, it would be so if the wire consisted of a circular loop and the time-varying magnetic field were centered within this loop. But baring special cases like this, it is not true that "the induced e.m.f per unit length in a closed circuit placed in a varying magnetic field is the same throughout the length of the loop".